# Getting item from Observable Collection or List()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, microsoft-metro

I have a ListBox called NotesList. I have an ObservableCollection called noteList, and I have a TextBox called NoteContents.

In my ObservableCollection, I set the Filename and Contents properties for a few items and then it gets added (bound) to my ListBox.

But now, I want to (when I click a button), show the "Contents" of the ListBox Item that was selected in the NoteContents TextBox.

How can I do this?

I currently have:

```
private void NotesList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NoteContents.Text = noteList.Where(x => x.Filename.Contains(NotesList.SelectedValue.ToString())).FirstOrDefault().Contents;
}
```

Comment: On ButtonClick or on SelectionChanged?

Comment: Please show what is in the Collection, and the XAML too.

Comment: Does your existing code not work or are you asking for a better solution? If the objects within your ObservableCollection implement INotifyPropertyChanged, you can do this in binding with UpdateSourceTrigger set to Explicit. This will then allow you to manually force a binding update in your button click handler / ICommand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without button clicks, just binding like:

```
<ListBox Name="NotesList" ItemsSource="{Binding YourObservableCollection}">
    <!--Your bindings here-->
</ListBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=NotesList, Path=SelectedItem.Contents}" />
```